# JavaFX IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, javafx

I know that there are a lot of questions on this topic, but none of them could help me.
I followed the instructions from the JetBrains website on connecting JavaFX to IntelliJ IDEA, registered all the necessary VM options:

```
--module-path
/home/zahar/IdeaProjects/openjfx-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
--add-modules = javafx.controls, javafx.fxml, javafx.graphics
--add-exports
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
```

my code is:

```
package web;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebPart extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start (final Stage stage) {

        Button buttonURL = new Button ("Load Page https://eclipse.org");
        Button buttonHtmlString = new Button ("Load HTML String");
        Button buttonHtmlFile = new Button ("Load File C: /test/a.html");

        final WebView browser = new WebView ();
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine ();

        buttonURL.setOnAction (new EventHandler <ActionEvent> () {

            @Override
            public void handle (ActionEvent event) {
                String url = "https://eclipse.org";
                // Load a page from remote url.
                webEngine.load (url);
            }
        });

        buttonHtmlString.setOnAction (new EventHandler <ActionEvent> () {

            @Override
            public void handle (ActionEvent event) {
                String html = "<html> <h1> Hello </h1> <h2> Hello </h2> </html>";
                // Load HTML String
                webEngine.loadContent (html);
            }
        });
        buttonHtmlFile.setOnAction (new EventHandler <ActionEvent> () {

            @Override
            public void handle (ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    File file = new File ("C: /test/a.html");
                    URL url = file.toURI (). ToURL ();
                    // file: / C: /test/a.html
                    System.out.println ("Local URL:" + url.toString ());
                    webEngine.load (url.toString ());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }

            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox ();
        root.setPadding (new Insets (5));
        root.setSpacing (5);
        root.getChildren (). addAll (buttonURL, buttonHtmlString, buttonHtmlFile, browser);

        Scene scene = new Scene (root);

        stage.setTitle ("JavaFX WebView (o7planning.org)");
        stage.setScene (scene);
        stage.setWidth (450);
        stage.setHeight (300);

        stage.show ();
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        launch (args);
    }
```

after starting, I get an error:

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.java.scene.web.WebViewHelper (in unnamed module @0x9efe064) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene to unnamed module @0x9efe064
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<clinit>(WebView.java:1271)
    at web.WebPart.start(WebPart.java:27)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application web.WebPart
```

I know that it is possible to register another --add-export where I add the desired class, but when I write

```
--add-exports
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper
```

The IDE tells me that ParentHelper is not part of javafx.graphics.
switching to another JDK is not a good idea.

Comment: now I removed the javafx.graphics from --add-modules, but exception is still the same

Comment: Include `javafx.web` in the `--add-modules` argument.

Comment: now it is
'Error: Could not find or load main class javafx.web
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.web'

Comment: You have spaces in the argument which might be illegal. Try `--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web`

Comment: It's works! Thank you very much, I was very inattentive